# Find maximum value of few column and print along with a matching column name

Tags: r

I have a dataframe for which has sale value for each zone for first three quarters of the year and its total

```
Zone Q1     Q2      Q3      total
a   15.21   53.31   80.1    109.04
b   19.2    52.35   71.5    84.1
c   10.24   28.56   70.41   100.05
d   11.94   38.58   59.72   76.34
e   11.05   37.32   53.34   67.97
```

I have to find the maximum sales value for each quarters along with the zone name. I used `sapply(df[,c(2:5)],function(X) max(X))`
got the maximum sales value for each quarter as well the total. which resulted in

```
Q1         Q2           Q3          Total
19.2       53.51        80.10       109.04
```

But it also requires the zone name for each maximum value. which function can be used to get the zone names or only way is to find each of the zone ,append it to a vector?

Comment: Perhaps `lapply(grep("Q\\d+", names(df1), value = TRUE), function(nm) df1[c('Zone',nm)][which.max(df1[[nm]]),])`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No it can be done like this. You can make the function accordingly.

```
sapply(df[,c(2:4)],function(X) df$Zone[which.max(X)])
```

Appreciate if this works.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this...

```
df2 <- df[,-1]

#difference columns to get quarterly sales (yours appear to be cumulative)
df2[,-1] <- df2[,-1]-df2[,-4]

#rename final quarter
names(df2)[4] <- "Q4"

#create data frame with best sales for each quarter
best <- data.frame(Zone=df$Zone[apply(df2, 2, which.max)],
                   Sales=apply(df2, 2, max))

best
   Zone Sales
Q1    b 19.20
Q2    a 38.10
Q3    c 41.85
Q4    c 29.64
```